# Building an enum inside a macro

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible to build an enum inside a Rust macro using fields that are defined as macro parameters? I've tried this:

```
macro_rules! build {
    ($($case:ty),*) => { enum Test { $($case),* } };
}

fn main() {
    build!{ Foo(i32), Bar(i32, i32) };
}
```

But it fails with `error: expected ident, found 'Foo(i32)'`

Note that if the fields are defined inside the enum, there is no problem:

```
macro_rules! build {
    ($($case:ty),*) => { enum Test { Foo(i32), Bar(i32, i32) } };
}

fn main() {
    build!{ Foo(i32), Bar(i32, i32) };
}
```

It also works if my macro only accepts simple fields:

```
macro_rules! build {
    ($($case:ident),*) => { enum Test { $($case),* } };
}

fn main() {
    build!{ Foo, Bar };
}
```

But I've been unable to get it to work in the general case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, but you're conflating totally unrelated concepts.

Something like `$case:ty` does not mean `$case` is something which *looks* like a type, it means `$case` is *literally* a type.  Enums are not made up of a sequence of types; they're made up of a sequence of *variants* which are an identifier followed (optionally) by a tuple structure body, a record structure body, or a tag value.

The parser doesn't care if the type you give it happens to coincidentally *look* like a valid variant, it's simply not expecting a type, and will refuse to parse one in that position.

What you need is to use something like `$case:variant`.  Unfortunately for you, *no such matcher exists*.  The only way to do something like this is to manually parse it using a recursive incremental parser and that is *so* out of scope of an SO question it's not funny.  If you want to learn more, try the [chapter on incremental TT munchers in the Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html) as a starting point.

However, you don't appear to *actually* do anything with the cases.  You're just blindly substituting them.  In that case, you can just cheat and not bother with trying to match anything coherent:

```rust
macro_rules! build {
    ($($body:tt)*) => {
        as_item! {
            enum Test { $($body)* }
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! as_item {
    ($i:item) => { $i };
}

fn main() {
    build!{ Foo, Bar };
}
```

(Incidentally, that `as_item!` thing is explained in the section on [AST coercion](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-ast-coercion.html) (*a.k.a.* "the reparse trick").)

This just grabs everything provided as input to `build!`, and shoves it into the body of an `enum` without caring what it looks like.

If you were trying to do something *meaningful* with the variants, well, you're going to have to [be more specific about what you're actually trying to accomplish](http://xyproblem.info/), as the best advice of how to proceed varies *wildly* depending on the answer.

Comment: We really need to promote *The Little Book of Rust Macros* to the level of official documentation to make your hard work easier to find!

Comment: Thanks, I already made extensive use of tlborm, but in this case, I was looking at things I could add _inside_ the `enum { }` (i.e. `enum { as_something!($($body)*)}` not realising that what was needed was to wrap the whole enum into `as_item`.

And a *huge* thanks for tlborm, I wouldn't be where I am with rust macros if not for it.

Comment: why does this example uses `{}` after `=>` when all the TRPL book examples use `()` ?