# How are multiple trait bounds expanded in a rust macro?

Tags: generics, rust, compiler-errors, compilation, macros

I have some Rust code equivalent to the snippet below, which doesn't compile

```
trait A {}
trait B {}

macro_rules! implement {
    ( $type:ty ) => {
        struct C<T: $type> { // <-- Changing "$type" to "A + B" compiles
            t: T,
        }
    }   
}

implement!(A + B); 

fn main() {}
```

Compiling it with `rustc 1.44.1` yields:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `,`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `for`, lifetime, or path, found `A + B`
```

while replacing `$type` with `A + B` compiles.

My question is why does this not compile as is, and how can it be changed to do so?

*(Note: a bit new to Rust, I am sure there's simpler ways to go about this problem, any advice would be beneficial)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ty` macro argument type serves a different purpose: it's a [type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html), not a [bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html). You may use multiple tokens for that:

```rust
macro_rules! implement {
    ( $($token:tt)* ) => {
        struct C<T: $($token)*> {
            t: T,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37007315/5397009