# Rust macro accept call to member function

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to replace a bunch of snippets like

```
if let Some(thing) = some_t {
    thing.doSomething();
}
```

with a macro, resulting in something like

```
if_some(some_t, doSomething());
```

so basically replacing

```
if_some(/* option */, /* member function call(s) */);
```

with

```
if let Some(thing) = /* option */ {
    thing./* member function call(s) */
}
```

The attempt below does however not seem to work (the compiler reports "error: unexpected token: `doSomething()`", which does not help me in understanding what is wrong here. Anyone has an idea on how to handle this?

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_some {
    ( $option:ident, $function:expr ) => {{
        if let Some(thing) = $option {
            thing.$function
        }
    }};
}

struct Thing {}

impl Thing {
    fn doSomething(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let some_t = Some(Thing {});

    if let Some(thing) = some_t {
        thing.doSomething();
    }

    if_some!(some_t, doSomething());
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same mistake as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006835/building-an-enum-inside-a-macro): `$function: expr` doesn't mean that `$function` looks like an expression, but it means that it _is_ literally a _complete_ expression and so can't be used as a subexpression in `thing.$function`. The solution is also the same as in the other question: use `$($function:tt)*` to capture an untyped token sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `doSomething()` is captured as `expr`, it will always stay so. The compiler does not see `thing.doSomething()`, it sees `thing.<expr>` and this is invalid Rust. You cannot write an expression after the dot, it needs to be an identifier.

The easiest way to fix that is to instead capture it as list of `tt`s. `tt`s can be inspected after they are captured:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! if_some {
    ( $option:ident, $($function:tt)* ) => {{
        if let Some(thing) = $option {
            thing.$($function)*
        }
    }};
}
```

Comment: makes sense, i thought the right hand side of the dot would be an expression as well... This seems to work, thank you!