# Use matched object in match arm as matched type in Rust? Is it possible?

Tags: rust

I am a beginner in Rust and I am trying to implement the visitor pattern for my simple compiler, where I implement AST entities and have visitors traverse the AST to generate code.

A central part of the process is the `visit_response()` function of a `visitor` (a trait) that accepts different types of AST entities and the visitor calls different functions in response.

The problem I have now is that I want to pass the matching object into the various visit_<>() functions, which have function signatures that corresponds to various AST entity types.

When I simply pass in the matching object, I get the error of "mismatched types expected `&ASLvalExpression`, found `ASEntitiesKind`".

Is there a way I can convert v, the matching object, into the various matched types so that I can use them as the match types in the matched arms? Can this be done? Thanks!

```
enum ASEntitiesKind {
  ASSimpleLval(i32, i32),
}

pub trait Visitable {
    fn get_struct_name(&self) -> &'static str;
    fn to_string(&self) -> &'static str;
    fn visit<'a, T: Visitor<&'a Self>>(&'a self, v: Box<T> )  {
        v.visit_response(self);
    }
}

pub trait Visitor<M> {
    fn visit_response<'a>(&self, v: M );
}

pub struct ASSimpleLval {
    m_pos: i32,
    m_value: i32,
}

impl Display for ASSimpleLval {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.m_value)
    }
}

impl Visitor<&ASEntitiesKind> for ASPrintAbsyn {
  fn visit_response<'a>(&self, v: &ASEntitiesKind ) {
    match v {
      ASEntitiesKind::ASSimpleLval(i1,i2) => {
        self.visit_simple_var(ASSimpleLval{m_pos: *i1, m_value: *i2});
      }
    }
  }
}

pub struct ASPrintAbsyn {}

impl ASPrintAbsyn {
  fn visit_simple_var(&self, v: ASSimpleLval) {
    println!("{}", v.to_string());
  }
}
```

I was expecting that the matching object can be used as an object of the matched type in the match arms.

===

Update:
I have updated the code as a mre. This code works, but sort of have things I don't like about it.

1. On every arm I need to destruct the enum types and reconstruct a complete new struct to pass into the various visit_<> functions.
2. As a consequence of 1, I would pass in a reference of a local var in the visit_response function to the visit_<> functions (in this example the newly created ASSimpleLval{} struct) instead of v: &ASEntitiesKind.

Are there better ways of writing this to address the two points above? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you expand your question with what `ASLvalExpression` is and how `ASEntitiesKind::ASSimpleLval(i32, Symbol)` or other variants should be used as such?

Comment: ASLvalExpression is just one of the kinds of AST entity, so is ASSimpleLval and ASIntConstant.

Comment: Mmm, in the code you've shown `ASSimpleLval` and `ASIntConstant` are *variants* of the `ASEntitiesKind` type, and are not types themselves, while the error indicates `ASLvalExpression` is a complete (and separate) type. It would be good to make your code a minimal example that reproduces your problem (a [mre](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: You can do this with `v @` syntax but then whatever you're calling has to match, too.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37007315/5397009

Comment: @kmdreko you were correct that ASLvalExpression is a complete separate type. In the updated example, ASLvalExpression is like ASSimpleLval, a complete type.

Comment: Note that enums and pattern matching largely make the visitor pattern redundant in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

While you can reconstruct the type inside of each `match` arm, it's much better to pattern-match each enum variant and give the inside parameters to the functions. For example, you may restructure your code like this:

```rust
enum ASEntitiesKind {
  ASSimpleLval(i32, Symbol),
  ASIntConstant(i32, i64),
  ...
}


impl Visitor<ASEntitiesKind> for ASPrintAbsyn {
  fn visit_response<'a>(&self, v: ASEntitiesKind ) {
    match v {
      ASEntitiesKind::ASSimpleLval(a, b) => {
        self.visit_simple_var(a, b);
      },
      ASEntitiesKind::ASIntConstant(a, c) => {
        self.visit_int_constant(a, c);
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Where a is `i32`, b is `Symbol` and c is `i64`. You can also use the same names, but it's more idiomatic to choose meaningful names here.